# SHGetImageList returns corrupted folder icon on Windows 7

Tags: windows, explorer

I've got a problem with default icons for folder on Windows 7.

I'm used to get icons with next code

```
    DWORD flags = directory ? FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY : FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;
    ...
        HICON largeIcon = NULL;

        SHGetFileInfo(filename.c_str(), flags, &shfi, sizeof(SHFILEINFO),
            SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);

        IImageList* imageList = NULL;
        HRESULT hResult = SHGetImageList(SHIL_JUMBO, IID_IImageList, (void**)&imageList);
        if (!imageList || hResult != S_OK)
            return NULL;

        hResult = imageList->GetIcon(shfi.iIcon, ILD_TRANSPARENT, &largeIcon);
        if (hResult != S_OK)
            return NULL;

        icon = LoadBitmapFromHicon(largeIcon);
        DestroyIcon(shfi.hIcon);
        DestroyIcon(largeIcon);
```

But it returns corrupted icon for folder. Another ones is fine.
I've applied grey filter over it. Original one looks the same.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM7pm.png

PS. I looks fine on W8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the same problem. But I use workaround:

```
function ExtractFolderIcon: HICON;
var
  Info: TSHStockIconInfo;
  Lib: HMODULE;
begin
  Info.cbSize := SizeOf(Info);
  OleCheck(SHGetStockIconInfo(SIID_FOLDER, SHGSI_ICONLOCATION, Info));
  Lib := LoadLibrary(Info.szPath);
  if Lib = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    Result := LoadImage(Lib, MAKEINTRESOURCE(-Info.iIcon), IMAGE_ICON, 256, 256, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
  finally
    FreeLibrary(Lib);
  end;
end;
```

Left image was received with your "classic" way, right with workaround:

[image]

Comment: I've got the same solution before asked. So I would say we have a winner.